# Multiple jquery sliders

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm struggling with a multiple jQuery slider -

In this scenario **if one slider increases the other sliders decreases accordingly**. The sliders are creating dynamically. I tried many examples but there is no luck.

I will explain the scenario if there is 3 slider and each set to 500, 1000,1500 , if I increase the value of first slider to 100(500+100) then 100 should be reduced from the other two(50 each).

I checked http://jsfiddle.net/jenishkottaram/sNfBM/14/
and  http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZLL/400/ but no help in my case.

Any help should be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

//slider starts here

```
drawSlider: function(elementId, sliderMax, sliderVal, rate) {   

 $("#" + elementId).each(function() {
  $( this ).empty().slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 0,
        max: sliderMax,
        value: sliderVal,
        step: 100,
     slide: function(event, ui) {
        // Update display to current value
        $(this).siblings().text(ui.value);

        // Get current total
        var total = 0;

        $("#" + elementId).not(this).each(function() {
            total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
        });
   // Need to do this because apparently jQ UI
        // does not update value until this event completes
        total += ui.value;

        var max = sliderMax - total;

        // Update each slider
        $("#" + elementId).not(this).each(function() {

            var t = $(this),
                value = t.slider("option", "value");

            t.slider("option", "max", max + value)
                .siblings().text(value + '/' + (max + value));
            t.slider('value', value);
        });
    }});});},
```

I'm using a for loop to dynamically display the sliders

```
    for (i = 0; i < aBal.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < balanceRange.length; j++) {
            if (aBal[i] == balanceRange[j]) {
                if (aCur[j] == activeCurrency) {
                    $('#account-wrapper-holder').append('<div class="account-wrapper">' +
                        '<h6>' + aName[j] + ':' + aNum[j] + '</h6>' +
                        '<p><span id="text-tot-allocate-value' + aName[j] + aNum[j] + '">Current cash balance: $' + balanceRange[j] + '</span>' +
                        '<span>Total to allocate:<input type="text" id="tot-allocate-value' + aName[j] + aNum[j] + '" value="' + balanceRange[j] + '" onchange="s.setValue(parseInt(this.value))"/></span></p>' +
                        '<div class="slider_class"><div class="cash-slider" id="slider-' + aName[j] + aNum[j] + '"></div>' +
                        '</div><span class="value">0</span><span class="var-account-total-balance" style="float:right;">$0</span></div>'
                    );
                                                                                       {

                    _this.drawSlider('slider-' + aName[j] + aNum[j] + '', sumOfCurrencyBalances, balanceRange[j], accountRate);
```

Comment: I need to add a multiple slider if one slider increase the other sliders decreases accordingly.Thanks for looking.

Comment: Ok, so you don't want the others to decrease accordingly?  That was the part I didn't get originally (you just had it as part of the description, without anything like "How do I get these other sliders to not change?").

Comment: You're updating the values of the other sliders; clearly that's what's making their values change.  Can you please clarify what exactly you want the code to do that it's not doing?

Comment: In this current scenario if I increase one slider the other two sliders is not decreasing (they even not changing automatically) something like this mortgage calculator http://www.estately.com/listings/info/115-46-inwood-st

Comment: Ok, we're making progress: you *want* them to change (and evidently they aren't).  So what are the other sliders doing?  Are they changing at all?  Also are you getting any JS errors or does it just fail silently?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes I want to change the sliders, currently its not changing automatically(one increase other decrease), no error ,its not working.according to this code its not entering the last section $("#" + elementId).not(this).each(function() { I put and alert, and there is no hope..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#" + elementId)
```

That means "give me a set of elements with only one element (the one with an ID of *elementId*)".

```
$("#" + elementId).not(this)
```

That means "give me that same set (of one element), and then give me all the elements in it which are not *this* (ie. every element except the one that's actually in there).

So in other words, it's just an empty set, and that explains why your alerts showed that you weren't iterating through it ... it had nothing to iterate through :-)

I think what you maybe want to do instead is add some class (eg. "slider") on all your sliders (actually I think jQuery UI might do this for you, so you could just use whatever class they add).  That way you could do:

```
$("." + thatClass).not(this)
```

which I think is more what you want.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks again. This is the class <div class="slider_class"><div id="slider-Margin87654321" class="cash-slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"> after I change this to $("." + slider_class).not(this) .each{}.. In this scenario the slider is not moving

Comment: You are close, but "slider_class" is the class, not a JS variable.  So instead of $("." + slider_class), just do: $(".slider_class").

Comment: one more question now the style is not taking I wrote custom style like .slider_class .ui-widget-content {....} but it takes the default .ui-widget-content{....}