# Create multiple Jquery sliders each in an individual web control - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web, slider

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days, so here goes:

I have a master,custom control (web control) that creates multiple web controls, programmatically, in a for loop, each containing a jquery slider. I have tried creating the slider with a javascript string, from code behind, by including a variable to change the slider div id, so that it is unique and not in conflict with other ones. The problem I have is that although the webcontrols are created, only the first jquery slider (in the first control) is created.

So:

Master Control

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //create the custom web control with sliders in each
        for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
        {
            CustomControl sliderControl = (CustomControl)LoadControl("CustomControl.ascx");
            sliderControl.SliderID = a;
            sliderControl.ID = "sliderControl_" + a;
            sliderControl.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
            thismaincontainerdiv.Controls.Add(sliderControl);

        }
    }
```

SliderControl - originally creating slider here but would cause conflict with any other slider control ID:

```
    <script>

$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);

        }
    });
    $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider").slider("value"));

});

    </script>

    <div id="slidercontainer" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:87px; background-color:lightgray">

<div id="sliderdescription" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:60px;">

    <div id="startblockdesc" runat="server" style="width:30px; height:100%; float:left"></div>

    <div id="descdiv" runat="server" style="position:relative; top:25px">
    <asp:Label ID="lbdescription" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:32px; font-size:20px; font-family:Helvetica" Text="Description"  ></asp:Label>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="sliderdiv" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:27px;">

    <div id="startblockslider" runat="server" style="width:40px; height:100%; float:left"></div>
    <div id="slider"></div>

</div>
```

Then to this, by not using the above for the slider control. Javascript allows me to change the ID of the div that is used for the slider:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stringSliderID = "slider_" + this.SliderID;

        string JavaScriptString = @"

              var sliderID = <SliderID>;

              var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
              slider.id = 'slider_' + sliderID;

              $(function () {
                  $('#slider_' + sliderID).slider({
                      value: 1,
                      min: 1,
                      max: 10,
                      step: 1,
                      slide: function (event, ui) {
                          $('#amount').val('$' + ui.value);

                      }
                  });
                  $('#amount').val('$' + $('#slider_' + sliderID).slider('value'));
              }); 


          ";

        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Slider", JavaScriptString.Replace("<SliderID>", this.SliderID.ToString()), true);         
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is this any clearer? I'll have a look at that link. Thanks for the comments already.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates the slider?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986434/multiple-jquery-sliders?rq=1 ??

Answer (score 0):

[To link that resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986434/multiple-jquery-sliders?rq=1)

This answered my question on how to create multiple sliders programmatically, on one page through jquery. However, I was unable to create an individual slider in a individual web control. But in the grand scheme of things there is a working solution. Many thanks.

Comment: The link is the one Learner provided.